# Unable to complete Creator Race Ruins

Tags: neverwinter-nights

I am playing the first Neverwinter Nights game, and I am trying to complete the Creator Race Ruins to get the Word of Power. It's the part where I have to use sundials to travel back in time and solve 3 puzzles to open some door.

The problem is all the puzzles refuse to work. For example in the **Ritual of Light** puzzle (where I place various gems in the water fountains), clicking on the center fountain displays this message:

> this pool looks as if it is being prepared to have some sort of magic cast upon it. strange runes have been scribed along its surface

The pool won't open its inventory so that I can grab the gems. Only this message displays. The same behavior goes for the **Smoke Ritual**. For the **Sound Ritual**, I play the gongs correctly, but it says something about the spells aren't complete yet.

For each puzzle, there is a gated door that leads to the puzzle (where the white spirals on the floor are). I just bashed the door down. I don't know if this is causing this problem or not.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are in the past, and the puzzles are still being prepared - you can't solve them until the preparations are complete. You'll have to solve them in the present instead.

Answer (score -2):

When in in present time make sure you first pick red color then blue color for primary color, for secondary color make sure you split a stack of 2x purple/blue gem, ones it's split put 1 one in each of secondary color pools, then it should be solved.

Comment: Are you sure your question stands on its own? If for some reason all other questions get removed, will yours answer the question for all people who come searching for a solution?

Comment: This answers a completely different question.